# How to format mongodb script using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using "MongoDB for VS Code" extension for scripting and running mongodb scripts. I used to format the script code by changing language to javascript and then format and then reverting file language to MongoDB to work. Can someone please let me know how can I associate JavaScript formatter to mongodb file extension without loosing the language support for mongodb.

Comment: the formatter is tied to the languageID so does the TextMate stuff and others, you can't pick stuff from other languages, solution write a formatter for MongoDB files

Comment: please share any guide or reference it will be helpful to create formatter for a language.

Comment: read the guide to writing extensions, there has to be an example formatter extension

Answer (score 0):

Came across this same problem this morning, as I started developing Atlas Functions & Aggregation Pipelines but wanted to test them quickly in my local playgrounds. This is what I came up with.

My quick config which enables Prettier and ESLint for MongoDB Playgrounds in VSCode, whilst keeping the Intellisense and MongoDB Playground syntax highlighting.

This requires the following VSCode extensions:

- [MongoDB for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mongodb.mongodb-vscode)
- [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Once the extensions are installed I configured a simple Node project loosely following [Add Eslint, Prettier, and Airbnb Style Guide to Your Project](https://dev.to/saurabhggc/add-eslint-prettier-and-airbnb-to-your-project-3mo8), adding the [AirBnB styles](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript).

```bash
npm init -y
npm i eslint-plugin-import eslint-config-airbnb-base eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier prettier -D
npx eslint --init
```

I use `.eslintrc.json` for configuration which I updated as follows

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.js", "**/*.mongodb"]
    }
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules/"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": "warn"
  }
}
```

Notice in the overrides section I have added `**/*.mongodb` to the files array. Which will allow ESLint to recognize `.mongodb` files and parse them as well.

Next I added `.prettierrc` which also includes `*.mongodb` in override files arrays.

```json
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.mongodb",
      "options": {
        "parser": "flow"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All this config actually has an added bonus, in that in `package.json` I have defined the following scripts.

```json
"scripts": {
  "lint:check": "eslint ./",
  "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ./",
  "style:check": "prettier --check ./",
  "style:fix": "prettier --write ./",
  "mongo:check": "prettier --check '**/*.mongodb'",
  "mongo:fix": "prettier --write '**/*.mongodb'",
}
```

I can run these from command line, and they can also be used with pre-commit hooks.

Coming back to VSCode Config, there are a few settings that I added. For prettier there is a setting called `prettier.documentSelectors` and for ESLint there are `eslint.validate` and `eslint.probe`.

```json
"prettier.documentSelectors": ["**/*.mongodb"],
"eslint.probe": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "html",
    "vue",
    "markdown",
    "mongodb"
],
"eslint.validate": ["mongodb"],
```

Best to add the above settings into the user settings, although the seem to work even when added to the workspace settings (`.vscode/settings.json`).

After applying all these I now have ESLint linting the `*.mongodb` files and Prettier formatting them as well on save.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/oizik/vscode-mongodb-playgrounds-prettier-eslint) with the config.